# How do I connect to HC-05 of Arduino in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, arduino, hc-05

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FlutterBluetoothSerial flutterBluetoothSerial =
      FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance;
  BluetoothDevice? device;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Start scanning for Bluetooth devices.
    flutterBluetoothSerial.();

    // Listen for scan results.
    flutterBluetoothSerial.scanResults.listen((scanResults) {
      for (var scanResult in scanResults) {
        if (scanResult.device.name == "HC-05") {
          device = scanResult.device;
          connectToDevice();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void connectToDevice() async {
    await device.connect();
    print("Connected to HC-05");

    // Send some data to the HC-05 module.
    device.write("Hello, world!");

    // Receive some data from the HC-05 module.
    String data = await device.read();
    print("Received data from HC-05: $data");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Connect to HC-05"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am not able to connect to HC-05 using this code. Can anyone point out the mistake in this or provide me with another way to connect to my module?

I want to receive a text from HC-05 but my Flutter app is not connecting to the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress("MAC Address HC-05"); //Use your MAC address here
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**